# Can Soaking prevent being Shaken?

Tags: savage-worlds, damage

Does a character still get Shaken if he Soaks all wounds that would be dealt by an attack? SW Deluxe has this to say on page 69:

> If the character is left with any wounds from an attack, he’s still
>   Shaken.

But it leaves it at that and this wording is quite unclear. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/13240) also says that Soaking all wounds would *remove* Shaken, but I cannot find anything to indicate this. Is this matter better explained in another book maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Shaken status is removed if you Soak all wounds from a single attack.

From page 78 of the Deluxe Explorer's Edition of the rules, under the Soak Rolls section:

> If a character Soaks all of the wounds from an attack, he removes his Shaken condition too (even from a previous source).